# Python Multiprocessing module processes raising runtime error and do nothing

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am trying to use multiprocessing module in python 2.7 to create a gui with wxpython that calls a separate module in a process that will graph things with matplotlib. However Everytime it calls that module, the gui instead just opens a copy of inself. Next I have tried using the multiprocessing module in a simple example. In the IDLE it appears to start the processes fine, but the processes don't actually run. When I run the code from the command line a attributeerror is raised, yet the code works fine when I switch all multiproccessing.Process to threading.Thread

Heres the command line code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8LTX.jpg

I've tested this module before and it seemed to have worked, so I am probably just doing something silly, however I can't figure out my error at all!

EDIT:

In my GUI changing the line from

```
queue_thread = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=simple_queue_model.main_func, args = (self.inputs,))
```

to:

```
queue_thread = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=simple_queue_model.main_func(self.inputs))
```

Causes the process to be called, however the main GUI window freezes until the process finishes running, and a new gui window is opened again which I don't understand.

EDIT 2:
the previous change just causes my GUI to call main_func no as a separate process. The line `queue_thread.start()` is what causes a new GUI to spawn, so overall this module isnt working at all for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start a new process with `multiprocessing` on Windows, a whole new virgin python process is started, which then imports the various modules you need and passes variables using `pickle`. In this case, you have defined your functions in the `__main__` namespace of the interactive session. To get them to run, save them to a module that y=can be imported from a new process. Be sure to consult the [guidelines](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming).

Conversely, threads can share memory and are directly passed the function definitions from the current namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the help! After going through the documentation and further testing after making the changes you suggested, I realized that the process is working, however in my gui I am redirecting stdout from the other module to a textctrl, and calling this modules function through a multiprocessing.Process() stops this redirection from happening (in IDLE the print statements aren't printed at all, in cmd they are printed in the cmd) which is why I thought the process wasn't working at all. Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Comment: @user3666665 I think to do that you either need to explicitly pass a handle to the `target` function, and redirect stdout in the `target` function to that handle, or have `stdout` in the `target` get redirected to a `multiprocessing.Queue` or `multiprocessing.Pipe`. Then have a thread in the parent process receive the messages being published, and have that thread update the textctrl using whatever thread-safe mechanism is provided by the GUI framework you're using. It might be worth asking a second question for this if you have trouble getting it working.

Comment: Have you considered using IPython.parallel or other libraries? Multiprocessing on Windows, frankly, is a pain, when you start dealing with access to the GUI and passing data back and forth. For my uses, I send feedback from subprocesses using sockets as shown here (http://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/logging-cookbook.html#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network
)

Comment: The reason I am using multiprocessing is because I want my gui to call a separate module that does calculations and then graphs the results without freezing the gui. When I use just the threading module as I've done in the past, I can only call this module once, I read in some other stackoverflow thread that I need to use the multiprocessing library instead to  get it to work for multiple calls. (And while it does, it's bringing a bunch of other problems with it). I'll take a look at what you've suggested though, thanks.

Comment: Feel free to ask your question about threading, if you don't think it's been answered already.